# How to get datepicker to work in Django forms

Tags: jquery, python, django, datepicker

I'm trying to get datepicker to work in my form in Django, but for some reason it's not working. I have jquery in my base template.

```
#forms.py

class ScheduleForm(forms.ModelForm):

    start_date = forms.DateField(widget=forms.DateInput(attrs={'class':'datepicker'}), initial=datetime.date.today, label="Start Date")

    # insert other fields here

    class Meta:
        model = Schedules
        fields = ('course_name', 'location', 'room', 'start_date', 'start_time', 'end_time', 'instructor', 'total_hours', 'hours_per_class', 'frequency', 'status', 'interval',)

#start_one_schedule.html

{% block main_content %}
<script>
    $(function() {
        $('.datepicker').datepicker({
            format: 'yyyy-mm-dd'
        });
    });
</script>
<h2>Initial Course Schedule</h2>
<br>
<form id="schedule_form" method="post" action="/schedule/start_one_schedule/">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.errors }}
    {% for field in form %}
        <table class="init_sched_form">
            <tr class="init_sched_row">
                <td class="init_sched_label">{{ field.label_tag }}</td>
                <td class="init_sched_field">{{ field }}</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    {% endfor %}
    <button type="submit" name="submit">Initial Schedule</button>
    <button type="submit" name="submit">Preview Schedule</button>
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

I have no idea what I'm doing wrong, because I've checked this with other answers. Do I need to do something in another module?

Edit: Here is my base.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

{% load staticfiles %}

<html>
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, width=device-width">
      <title>{% block title %}{% endblock %}</title>
      <!-- Font Awesome -->
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
      <!-- Ionicons -->
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ionicons/2.0.1/css/ionicons.min.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'css/bootstrap.min.css' %}">
      <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'css/AdminLTE.min.css' %}">
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'css/skin-blue.min.css' %}">
      <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

      <!-- Optional theme -->
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

      <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
      <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    </head>
    <body class="hold-transition skin-blue sidebar-mini">

      <script src="{% static 'js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js' %}"></script>
      <script src="{% static 'js/bootstrap.min.js' %}"></script>
      <script src="{% static 'js/AdminLTE.min.js' %}"></script>


    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: There are many datepickers out there. Could you elaborate on which one you're trying to use? Perhaps with a link to it's homepage?

Comment: http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/

Comment: What is the HTML generated for the `start_date` field? Is the class attribute in there?

Comment: I have the form looped for each field.

Comment: can you check the console to see if you get some error?

Comment: Please show the template where you are including the files for jQuery and datepicker.

Comment: I made an edit to my question.